# Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection

Tags: php, concrete5-5.7, concrete5-8.x

In a page on my concrete5 site and added the rss feed block. For getting feed from blog. Gettting the following error:

Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection www.blog.com: make sure the "sslcafile" or "sslcapath" option are properly set for the environment

any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has to do with your server. It says it can't load data from a website with SSL (https) because your server do not have a certificate authority file installed.
Please check :

1. Your apache has ssl_module (mod_ssl) active
2. PHP has these extensions enabled : php_openssl & php_curl
3. If your php.ini has a correct absolute path defined to your certificate authority ( curl.cainfo & openssl.cafile )

-

If your installation does not have a CA-file , then :

1. download this file: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. add to your php.ini

   curl.cainfo = "< path-to-cacert.pem >"
   openssl.cafile = "< path-to-cacert.pem >"